# Are logging tools like log4j useful only during development phase?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I need to log the activity of the users connected to my server, should I use log4j? Or is log4j beneficial only during development phase?

Comment: FYI, rather than get locked into one particular logging framework, you can use the [`SLF4J`](http://www.slf4j.org) logging façade. Your code calls SLF4J interface methods which in turn calls the logging framework of your choice plug-and-play style. Works with [`LogBack`](http://logback.qos.ch), Log4j, the system default logging for Java and for Android, and more.

Comment: SLF4J locks you in the past though. Its API  only supports logging Strings, not Objects. It also creates more garbage than necessary. To get the full benefits of upcoming Log4j 2 features like binary logging I recommend using the Log4j 2 API in your applications. There is a log4j-to-slf4j adapter if you change your mind, so you won't be locked in. Disclosure: I am a Log4j 2 committer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are actually not particularly useful during development, System.out.println is pretty good for most dev debug logging, but once you deploy the following abilities become really useful:

- roll logfiles so they don't get too big allowing for continuous maintenance-free operation
- add times/dates so you can look at the logs for a certain time period
- Change verbosity on the fly (You don't always want trace or debug info, but being able to flip it on when he system isn't running well can be a lifesaver)
- Re-route logfiles to a more accessible place... Log4j can send your logs to various databases or other locations for when you can't actually reach your server directly.

Some of our code has trace statements on every significant line.  If we run into problems when we are developing we leave the debugging/trace statements in and are able to turn them on when we need to in production--almost equivalent to single-stepping through your deployed code.  In addition most methods have trace or debug statements at the top showing the parameters being passed in and program flow--again only really useful for a deployed system where a debugger is unavailable.

So in short, yes it's useful after development.

edit (in response to comment question)--

Just as an example.  The app I'm working on now has 20ish logs.  One is "Performance", it logs data coming in including timings--sometimes more than one line a second.  This logfile "Rolls" at 10mb (about hourly) but we use it to find lags in our data delivery.  We even use other software to analyze this log sometimes to look for patterns in data timing.

We have a separate "Error" log that logs all error-level activity.  This log doesn't roll so fast that we lose data when we are getting a bunch of other log information.

There is another log to put problems related to Hibernate/SQL and one for problems related to our message queue and one for our inter-app cache....

These are all also combined into a "main" log through the log4j config file.  We can reconfigure any one log to a different level (for instance, we were having authentication problems with a data source so we turned up it's debugging level on that source to find out what had changed in our server's environment to cause that)

Even though some of the logs scroll 10mb in an hour (our max file size).  Log4j will roll them into .1 and .2 files so we can keep 10-50 of them depending on need.

All of this is done through config files and can be changed after deployment without rebuilding the system.

Edit 2--another thought

Another useful point about using log4j and the java logging interface is that libraries like hibernate using it can be configured through xml files without rebuilding.

Without Log4j/java's logging APIs you would either A) have a custom API to control the logs, B) only have default logging or C) have no logging from that subsystem.  Since Hibernate uses java's APIs however, you can set the log level for "Hibernate" log info in a standard, documented xml config file and even re-route it's logs to a database or other logging device.

Comment: Can you tell how exactly logging levels help? I mean even with different logging levels, in the end I'll see it as one big log file, right?

Comment: Under normal operation you only want to see highlights--errors/exceptions and some high level processing events (info).  When you are having problems you can change the log level (through the app or editing the config file) and get any info like (from my examples above) exactly what direction an "if" went or what parameters were passed into each method.  Normally these would scroll the important info off the file too fast.

Comment: Suppose the logger was set with "Warn" in config file and i was logging with "Info" level. Now will I be able to see the previous "info" level logs after i change the config file to "Info" level?

Comment: But log4j is not useful for logging "historical" data, right? For example, uber must be logging all the data of all the transaction a user has done or all the requests the driver has cancelled, etc, for such scenarios log4j isn't useful, right?

Comment: @Tejas You are right, you will not be able to see "debug" data on an info system by setting it to debug after the fact, however many problems are cyclic, when you have identified that there is a problem you can change the setting to debug or trace and get more information the next time the problem occurs without restarting the server.

Comment: @Tejas I'd say that it's not a great idea to use log4j on data that MUST be retained (by law) or data that you wish to consume with a program.  It can be used in both these cases, but there are better solutions for both.

Answer (score 1):

Logging is especially useful to locate errors that occur in productive code. During development you can use more powerful tools like debuggers.

Of course you have to be aware that logging potentially affects performance and can create huge files. That's why tools like log4j can be configured to turn on and off logging or to control its verbosity.

It's ok to use log4j because it is the most common library for Java. However I personally find its configuration a bit unitntuitive.

Comment: The Log4j 1.2 configuration was cumbersome and unintuitive, but this has been much improved in Log4j 2.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for using loggers such as Log4j is to allow for different logging levels for different components. Logs can get pretty large and messy if you turn DEBUG on for everything. If you know what area of code you want to "magnify" in your logs you can ratchet up the logging for that area alone.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes (or any other logging framework / [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org))
2. no